# SwiftUI remove extraneous padding on borderless Menu in toolbar

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In the following example, I'm trying to remove padding so that "A" looks like "C". I can't find any way to remove this padding for a `Menu` when inside a ToolbarItemGroup (tested in iOS 15 or iOS 16). There shouldn't be any space between the green and red borders in "A". This is clearly controlled by `.buttonStyle(.borderless)` for a Button, but the corresponding `.menuStyle(.borderlessButton)` does not work when in a toolbar (but does work when no in a toolbar). Any ideas?

```
@main
struct TestApp: App {
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      ScrollView{}.toolbar {
        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
          HStack {
            Button {

            } label: {
              Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                .border(Color.red)
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderless) // <--Removed in "B" below.
            .border(Color.green)
            Menu {
              EmptyView()
            } label: {
              Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                .border(Color.red)
            }
            .menuStyle(.borderlessButton) // <--Removed in "B" below.
            .border(Color.green)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post entire code. I have just copied your button code inside toolbar item group and I don't see any extra spaces.

Comment: Added the wrapping code as well. I ran this with XCode 14.0 (14A309) on iOS 16.0 iPhone 14 Pro simulator (though it reproduces on 15.5 as well, and with other simulators). Technically the HStack is optional in there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you've solved it already or not. I just met this issue too. As a temporary workaround, I use negative values to remove those unwanted paddings.

```swift
Menu {
  EmptyView()
} label: {
  Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
    .border(Color.red)
}
.padding(EdgeInsets(top: -4, leading: -8, bottom: -4, trailing: 0))
// Or use the extension .ky_removeNavigationBarMenuButtonPadding() as describe below.
```

And you can add a View extension to reuse this adjustment so that we can quickly replace it in the future if a better solution comes along.

```swift
extension View {
  public func ad_removeNavigationBarMenuButtonPadding(includingTrailing: Bool = false) -> some View {
    modifier(RemoveNavigationBarMenuButtonPaddingModifier(includingTrailing: includingTrailing))
  }
}

private struct RemoveNavigationBarMenuButtonPaddingModifier: ViewModifier {
  let includingTrailing: Bool
  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content.padding(EdgeInsets(top: -4, leading: -8, bottom: -4, trailing: (includingTrailing ? -8 : 0)))
  }
}
```

As a note on the parameter `includeTrailing`, if your menu button is not on the edge trailing side, you will need to remove the trailing padding as well.